# How to create custom Remember me provider in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, authorization, remember-me

I will explain my problem. I am logging in users using an API passing username and encrypted password, so I am unable to load users only by username.

I am using GUARD to get the user details and authorize the users for a given firewall. So far so good.

My problem begins when I wan to activate the remember me. Obviously as the user is not stored in my database, the remember me fails to load the user by name.

At the moment I overcome the issue implementing the class RememberMeServicesInterface and using my new class in my guard class that extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator.

To be honest to me it feels like an hack as I am pretty much sure there must be a better way to do this.

Checking the code I have noticed that Symfony has 2 classes that implement RememberMeServiceInterface,  TokenBasedRememberMeServices and PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices, can someone explain me how could I inject also my RememberMeService and use that to authorize my user?

Thanks in advance to the community for the help.

Answer (score 7):

I have finally found a way to achieve custom remember me.
These are the steps:

1) Create a class that extends Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\RememberMeFactory

This class overrides getKey() with a custom key and create() so I can inject my own token service security.authentication.rememberme.services.MYCUSTOMTOKENSERVICE

2) Create a token service that extends Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\TokenBasedRememberMeServices so that I could use my authentication logic and my custom UserProvider function

3)Create a listener that extends Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener

4)Bind together in my service yml file

customlistener.security.authentication.listener:
          class: #####
          public: false

security.authentication.rememberme.services.customtokenservice:
          class: ###
          parent: "security.authentication.rememberme.services.abstract"
          abstract: true

5) In security.yml I use the string I used in getKey to recall my listener  custom-remember-me with same options of remember-me key

Worked like a charm !

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Were you able to tie this together with your Guard implementation?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás did you try doing something similar as soipo? I'm interested in knowing the answer too if this is a working solution

Comment: @Christian No, not yet. I just recently managed to upgrade to symfony 2.8, so couldn't yet get my hands on using Guard. I'd be sure to post my solution as soon as I worked it out.